# Create new file for new date in java

Tags: java

I have a large csv file from which i m reading data. So once the date change in that file I'm suppose to create new file and store data in new file.Suppose initialy date is 2012-05-29 then I'll store that date in 1.csv file and if the date changes to 2012-05-30 in the original csv file I'll store data in 2.csv

Problem is that I'm able to create new file named 2.csv but no data goes in that file
Please help me with it

My code:

```
public class DateConverter {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String date = "2012-05-29";
        String olddate = "2012-05-29";
        int count = 1;
        String output = "D:\\usdinr_t\\" + count + ".csv";
        CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter(output);
        try {
            CsvReader reader = new CsvReader("D:\\usdinr_t\\try.csv");
            reader.readHeaders();
            while (reader.readRecord()) {
                date = reader.get("date");
                if (!(olddate.equals(date))) {
                    writer.close();
                    writer.flush();
                    count = 2;
                    output = "D:\\usdinr_t\\" + count + ".csv";
                    writer = new CsvWriter(output);

                    olddate = date;
                }
                System.out.println(reader.get("date"));
                writer.write(reader.get("date"));
                writer.write(reader.get("ltp"));
                writer.endRecord();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("FIle not found");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `no data goes to the file`? Where does it go?

Comment: Have you tried debugging..??

Comment: have you tried closing and flushing your writer at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what may be going on is that the final file is never closed and flushed. You only close and flush the file when a new one is created.